# The system shows there exist some invalid syntax

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from numpy import *
w = array([  1.81346086e-01,  -1.36591166e-02,  -1.73345720e-01,
        -1.02855865e-02,  -1.32613285e-01,   3.90886640e-02,
        -2.40393403e-02,   1.78065375e-01,   2.88840308e-02,
         5.60636772e-02,   9.32465454e-02,  -3.50576621e-02,
        -2.12385181e-03,   6.13781357e-02,  -9.53637135e-03,
        -1.22448199e-02,   4.58332368e-02,  -1.12394726e-01,
         7.09812971e-02,  -9.73976394e-02,  -2.48869702e-01,
        -5.69279004e-02,  -1.98330278e-02,  -5.74863766e-02,
         7.87791471e-02,  -3.38030279e-02,  -1.84575948e-03,
        -1.16952122e+00,  -1.90923792e-02,   5.59990037e-01,
        -1.50134434e-02,  -4.89514694e-02,  -9.53637135e-03,
        -1.57276308e-02,   1.06904554e-02,  -3.22008502e-02,
         2.21072372e-02,  -1.18086312e-01,   4.86338654e-02,
        -2.04002494e-01,  -3.49362471e-02,  -3.38795234e-01,
        -2.36907182e-02,  -7.80980698e-02,   1.09363592e-01,
         3.04889251e-02,   3.00815894e-02,   6.11360154e-02,
        -4.74272403e-01,  -5.24759799e-02,  -3.40871772e-02,
        -4.82527164e-02,  -5.91913399e-03,   1.06382623e-01,
        -2.87304357e-02,   1.35501465e-02,  -3.58802903e-01,
         6.31486114e-02,  -3.61248551e-03,  -1.94682943e-02,
         2.56087637e-02,  -9.71239742e-02,  -8.85061157e-03,
        -1.73177194e-01,  -1.32828208e-01,  -4.43088591e-02,
        -3.25854698e-02,  -6.41789111e-03,  -1.56001129e-02,
        -1.63489755e-01,  -1.19453204e-02,   3.24993076e-02,
         1.93675973e-01,   4.32882150e-02,   0.00000000e+00,
         8.12154517e-02,  -1.97196742e-01,  -3.80870804e-02,
         9.07157836e-02,  -1.64033979e-01,   7.35196340e-02,
        -5.33040216e-03,   1.22776940e-01,  -2.42623502e-02,
        -4.26551237e-02,  -6.83593168e-01,  -1.01729835e-01,
        -4.80802058e-02,  -1.17281962e-01,   1.07104455e-02,
        -6.58264777e-03,  -1.69677979e-02,   1.40977823e-01,
         0.00000000e+00,   3.76676568e-03,   4.88984148e-02,
        -1.30720975e-01,   1.76312618e-02,   4.32368390e-02,
         1.19509840e-01,  -1.79071105e-01,   5.51654434e-02,
         7.81933648e-02,  -6.41732796e-03,  -7.39420138e-03])
        
        
File "warm3.py", line 3
     w = array([  1.81346086e-01,  -1.36591166e-02,  -1.73345720e-01,
                ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what's wrong! I just copy the resulting data(the array above) and assign it to w.
Even if I delete the space, it is still wrong.
I really don't know what happend.

Comment: @philipyoo He is trying to create a numpy array.

Comment: Is it possible the is a non-printable character pasted in accidentally somewhere between `[` and `1` ?

Comment: Have you copy and paste your own code from the question and reproduced the error?

Comment: Works for me too. I'm voting mutant zombie character in your file. Especially in a non-ascii unicode world, its easy to get a character that looks right, but baffles python.

Comment: Then what can I do?

Comment: The original data is 819*1, it's too long to copy here. So I delete some of them. If there is some zombie character in my file, then what can I do? I need to operate these data